# Alert css and class name by Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Необходимо по нажатию клавиши **Фигура** отображать css и class name конкретного элемента.
В текущей реализации не могу получить данные о стилях конкретного div.

Пример кода:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        $("#myTable").find('tbody')
            .append($('<tr>')
                .append($('<td>')
                    .append($("<div>")
                    .attr({
                        'class': $("#figure :selected").val(),
                    })
                    .css({
                        "background-color": $("#colour :selected").val(),
                    }))
                    )
                .append($('<td>')
                    .append($('<button>Удалить</button>')
                        .click(function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $(this).parent().parent().remove()
                        }))
                    )
                .append($('<td>')
                    .append($('<button>Фигура</button>')
                        .click(function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            console.log($(this).parent().parent().children('td').children('div'))
                        }))
                    )
                )
                
    });

    $("#hide").click(function(){
        var clas = $("#figure :selected").val();
        
        var color = $("#colour :selected").val();
        
        var row = $('div').filter(function() {
            var color1 = $(this).css("background-color");
            var clas1 = $(this).attr('class')
            return color1 === color && clas1 === clas
        })
        row.parent().parent().hide()
    });

    $("#show").click(function(){
        var clas = $("#figure :selected").val();
        
        var color = $("#colour :selected").val();
        
        var row = $('div').filter(function() {
            var color1 = $(this).css("background-color");
            var clas1 = $(this).attr('class')
            return color1 === color && clas1 === clas
        })
        row.parent().parent().show()
    });
})
```

```css
.square {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }

.circle {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="colour">
   <option selected>Список с цветами</option>
   <option value="rgb(255, 0, 0)">Красный</option>
   <option value="rgb(0, 128, 0)">Зеленый</option>
   <option value="rgb(0, 0, 255)">Синий</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" id="add">Добавить фигуру</button>
  <button type="button" id="hide">Скрыть фигуры</button>
  <button type="button" id="show">Показать фигуры</button>
 </div>
 <div>
  <select id="figure">
   <option selected>Список с фигурами</option>
   <option value="circle">Круг</option>
   <option value="square">Квадрат</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" id="sort_name">Сортировать по цвету А-Я</button>
  <button type="button" id="sort_name">Сортировать по фигуре А-Я</button>
 </div>
 <div>
  <table id="myTable">
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Какой `alert`?

Comment: По нажатию на кнопку "Фигура", с помощью alert ("сообщение") выводить стиль/имя класса элемента div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {
    $("#myTable").find('tbody')
      .append($('<tr>')
        .append($('<td>')
          .append($("<div>")
            .attr({
              'class': "shape " + $("#figure").val(),
            })
            .css({
              "background-color": $("#colour").val(),
            }))
        )
        .append($('<td>')
          .append($('<button>Удалить</button>')
            .click(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              $(this).closest("tr").remove()
            }))
        )
        .append($('<td>')
          .append($('<button>Фигура</button>')
            .click(function(e) {
              var el = $(this).closest("tr").find(".shape")[0];
              var classes = [...el.classList].join(",");
              var style = getComputedStyle(el);
              console.log(classes);
              console.log(JSON.stringify(style));
            }))
        )
      )

  });

  $("#hide").click(function() {
    var clas = $("#figure").val();
    var color = $("#colour").val();

    var row = $('div').filter(function() {
      var color1 = $(this).css("background-color");
      var clas1 = $(this).attr('class')
      return color1 === color && clas1 === clas
    })
    row.parent().parent().hide()
  });

  $("#show").click(function() {
    var clas = $("#figure").val();

    var color = $("#colour").val();

    var row = $('div').filter(function() {
      var color1 = $(this).css("background-color");
      var clas1 = $(this).attr('class')
      return color1 === color && clas1 === clas
    })
    row.parent().parent().show()
  });
})
```

```css
.square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="colour">
    <option selected>Список с цветами</option>
    <option value="rgb(255, 0, 0)">Красный</option>
    <option value="rgb(0, 128, 0)">Зеленый</option>
    <option value="rgb(0, 0, 255)">Синий</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" id="add">Добавить фигуру</button>
  <button type="button" id="hide">Скрыть фигуры</button>
  <button type="button" id="show">Показать фигуры</button>
</div>
<div>
  <select id="figure">
    <option selected>Список с фигурами</option>
    <option value="circle">Круг</option>
    <option value="square">Квадрат</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" id="sort_name">Сортировать по цвету А-Я</button>
  <button type="button" id="sort_name">Сортировать по фигуре А-Я</button>
</div>
<div>
  <table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```